# Raster as output in processing plugin

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

I'm creating a QGIS plugin, implementing RichDem (python/c++) algorithms. However, I'm struggling to find a way to initialize a raster and serve it as output to my algorithm.

```py
def convert_raster_to_numpy_array(lyr: QgsRasterLayer) -> np.array:
    provider: QgsRasterDataProvider= lyr.dataProvider()
    block = provider.block(1,lyr.extent(),lyr.width(),lyr.height())
    switcher = {
        1: np.byte, #byte,
        10: np.float32, #CFloat32, float
        11: np.float64, #CFloat64, double
        8: np.int16, #CInt16, short
        9: np.int32, #CInt32, intc
        6: np.float32, #Float32, np.single
        7: np.float64, #Float64, np.double
        3: np.int16, #Int16,
        5: np.int32, #Int32,
        2: np.uint16, #UInt16,
        4: np.uint32, #UInt32,
    }
    npdata = np.frombuffer(block.data(),dtype = switcher.get(provider.dataType(1)))
    return np.reshape(npdata, (lyr.width(), lyr.height()))


class Algorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = "INPUT"
    OUTPUT = "OUTPUT"

    def initAlgorithm(self, config):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr("Input layer"),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeRaster],
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(
                self.OUTPUT, self.tr("Output layer")
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        dem = self.parameterAsRasterLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        filled = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)

        dem_array = convert_raster_to_numpy_array(dem)
        dem_array = dem_array*2
        # add magic here so that filled actually contains a clone of the raster where I can put the data back

        return {self.OUTPUT: filled}
```

So far, I've tried `filled = dem.clone()`, which crashes QGIS, I've looked at the [source code for raster calculator](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html?highlight=parameterasrasterlayer#qgis.core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm.parameterAsOutputLayer), where they also use a `QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination`, that they then use as a `parameterAsOutputLayer`.
The problem lies in actually making a layer (allocating memory, so to speak), so that I can copy the data over from the array.

*EDIT:* The `filled` is a string and points to a temporary file location. I think saving a raster there should work?